# What would be the Java equivalent of WCF

Tags: java, wcf

To my endless disbelief I discovered the .NET stack doesn't have the answer for everything. Is there a software parallel to WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) in Java or is WCF the only WCF out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at JMS (The Java Messaging Service) activeMQ (http://activemq.apache.org/) is a good implementation. You also might want to look at Java EE.